# General Relativity: Christoffel symbol identity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

> I want to show that
>   $$\Gamma ^{\mu}_{\mu \nu}=\partial _\nu (\ln \sqrt{|g|}) .$$
>   (Here $|g|$ denotes the determinant of the metric.)

Working out the left hand side:\begin{align}
\Gamma ^{\mu}_{\mu \nu} &= \dfrac{1}{2} g^{\mu \rho}(\partial _{\mu} g_{\nu \rho } + \partial _{\nu} g_{\rho \mu} - \partial _{\rho} g_{\mu \nu})\\
&= \dfrac{1}{2} g^{\mu \rho} \partial _{\nu} g_{\rho \mu}
\end{align}
where I've used the symmetry of the metric.

The right hand side yields
\begin{align}
\partial _\nu (\ln \sqrt{|g|})&= \dfrac{1}{2|g|}\partial _\nu |g|\\
&= \dfrac{1}{2}|g^{-1}|\partial _\nu |g|
\end{align}

A definition for the determinant of the metric is 
\begin{align}
\tilde{\epsilon}^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}|g|= \tilde{\epsilon}_{\mu' \nu' \rho' \sigma'} g^{\mu' \mu}g^{\nu' \nu}g^{\rho' \rho}g^{\sigma' \sigma} 
\end{align}
where $\tilde{\epsilon}^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}$ is the Levi-Cevita symbol.

My questions:

- Is what I've done so far correct?
- How can I match the result $\dfrac{1}{2} g^{\mu \rho} \partial _{\nu} g_{\rho \mu}$ with $\dfrac{1}{2}|g^{-1}|\partial _\nu |g|$? I don't see how to incorporate the definition of the determinant...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*I am not sure for the correctness of your equation with Levi-Civita symbol*.

Instead, I recommend using the **Jacobi's formula** for derivative of matrix determinant. Taking the equation from [corollary part of wikipedia's page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula#Corollary) (as more suitable for our needs) and after subsituting some symbols (to avoid confusion in application of this to GR) we have
$$
\frac{d}{d\lambda} \det[ g_{\mu\nu}] = \frac{d}{d\lambda} \det[ g(\lambda)] = \det[ g(\lambda)] \, \mathrm{tr} \left[g(\lambda)^{-1} \, \frac{d}{d\lambda} g(\lambda)\right] = \det[ g(\lambda)] \,\, g^{\mu\nu} \frac{d}{d\lambda} g_{\nu\mu}.
$$

Since variable $\lambda$  could be anything, including coordinate variable $x^{\nu}$, it means that the right hand side of your original equation could be written as 
$$
\partial_\nu\left(\ln\sqrt{|g|}\right)= \frac12 |g|^{-1} \partial_\nu{|g|} =\frac12 g^{\mu\rho}\partial _\nu g_{\rho\mu},
$$
which is what you already obtained for the left hand side. *Note:* obviously, $g$ does not change sign, so the $|\dots|$ does not affect differentiation.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question! 
I still have a remark about your note: why is it obvious that g does not change sign?

Comment: @user52125: Since the sign change of $g$ would mean that the metric signature changed. Also, if $g$ passes zero it would mean that metric is degenerate at some point.